# Can I have templates for rst files with Sphinx?

Tags: jinja2, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have several rST pages that follow the same skeleton, but with different values and paragraphs in some places.

Ideally, I would imagine something like this (*simplified example*):

`page-model.rst`

```
 Feature {% block title %}Index{% endblock %}
 ============================================     
 {% block description %}
 Not available.
 {% endblock %}
```

And then:

`page-1.rst`

```
 {% extends "page-model.rst" %}

 {% block title %}Load{% endblock %}

 {% block description %}
 Load data from hard disk.
 {% endblock %}
```

Is that possible out of the box?

Should I hack something myself to run Jinja before generating docs? Or define my own directives?

Is that a bad idea? :)

Thanks for your insights!

Comment: Quite sure this would need to be done as a pre-process on the RST files. Though you could probably hack this into your `conf.py`... this isn't very conventional RST use.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: This is described well here: https://www.ericholscher.com/blog/2016/jul/25/integrating-jinja-rst-sphinx/